# XState doesn't stay in idle state

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vuex, state-machine, xstate

I am using `xstate` together with `vuex` in my application:

- `vuex` handles the user, api calls, response items, etc.
- `xstate` handles mainly complex form interactions.

Due to the reason, that complex forms contain multiple components, which communicate with each other I have to implement `xstate` *not* on a component level, but inside `vuex`. Inside the xstate visualizer it seems to work:

[image]

[image]

I can switch between the state, but in the real application it can't go back to its initial state (idle) and then **stay** there. It always transitions back to the next one. I don't know what I am doing wrong, but I have console logged the formState getter and the output looks like this:

```sh
formState idle 
formState createImageContent
```

(it immediately switches away from idle state)

Here is the basic example of the implementation: https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-shape-b4lgk

Comment: Have you tried simplifying the example? When I removed the Vuetify part, then it worked without issues for me.

Comment: @Kunukn Thank you for the comment, I haven't tried it without `Vuetify`, because the real application (where this problem occurs) is much bigger and depends on `Vuetify`, but I will have a closer look on it now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is in your `Form.vue` component. In this line to be precise:

```html
<v-window v-model="$store.getters['form/formState'].value">
```

I'm no Vuetify expert so I do not know why exactly is `v-window` updating the `v-model` with the value `createImageContent` but it definitely does. I found the problem by activating Vuex [strict mode](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/strict.html) which raises error whenever some state is mutated outside of mutation. It throws an error and from the stack trace you can see the problem is caused by `v-window` mutating the `$store.getters['form/formState'].value`

Easy fix is not using `v-model` and use `:value` instead:

```html
<v-window :value="$store.getters['form/formState'].value">
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/xstate-doesnt-stay-in-idle-state-pbfoh)

**Update**

OK, I found the reason. `v-window` has a [undocumented](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-window/#component-pages) prop `mandatory` ([source](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/18c2d6ce95978cd2b75a6eaace45141deaa7dbad/packages/vuetify/src/components/VWindow/VWindow.ts#L35)) which is `true` by default. In this mode, the `v-window` is expecting (and enforcing) that at least one of `<v-window-item>` child components is active at all times. When you set state to `idle`, there is no `<v-window-item>` with such value so it picks one of the items itself (first not disabled) and updates `v-model`. So another solution is to add `:mandatory="false"` to `<v-window>`.

But not using `v-model` is probably safer and cleaner as Vuex getter should never be used with `v-model`